# Find unused variables in LESS

Tags: less, unused-variables

I'd like to get notified by the LESS compiler about the unused variables in my LESS stylesheets.

I can't find anything useful. How can I do?

**NB** (for the one that downvoted):

I'm talking about the LESS compiler because I want to get notified about real unused variables, not just some simple regex. This because I use variables names interpolation in my code.

Comment: Afaik, there's no such tool. You could try some `regexp` based thing like in the comment above - but this method does not really detect all possible variable usage (e.g. it won't catch indirect variable referencing).

Comment: @AndréDion and you could see that it's talking about SCSS (+ it miss the indirect variable referencing that I use)

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's SCSS/LESS—the technique is the same. Ultimately what does it really matter? The resulting CSS won't be affected by unused preprocessor variables.

Comment: It matters, because I need to find real unused variables. If a variable is used by interpolation. I don't want to get notified about it. About the "it just works", when you have a large code base and you want to clean up the code, you end up asking questions like this one...

Comment: Asking for suggestions about 3rd party software is off topic for SO.

Comment: I'm asking about a configuration of the Less compiler. Not about a software actually.